# Precedence in Strings in Java

Tags: java

what is the explanation of this precedence in strings in java?

```
public class PrecedenceInStrings {

public static void main(String[] args){

int x = 3;
int y = 5;

String s6 = x + y + "total";
String s7 = "total " + x + y;
String s8 = " " + x + y + "total";

System.out.println(s6 + "\n" + s7 + "\n" + s8);
}
}
```

output:

8total

total 35

35total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compiler processes operators `+` in your expressions left to right. When it comes to the first `+` in

```
x + y + "total"
```

it sees `int`s on both sides, so it performs an addition. When Java compiler processes the second `+`, it sees an `int` and a `String`, and interprets the operator as string concatenation.

In your second and third expressions the left-hand side of the `+` operator  is a string, so all operators get interpreted as concatenations.

If you want to force a specific order of operations, use parentheses. For example, if you would like to get the total in your third example, parenthesize the addition, like this:

```
String s8 = " " + (x + y) + "total";
```