# when is addition taking place and when is concatenation taking place in the case of the below 4 cases?

Tags: java, string, integer, numbers, concatenation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;

        System.out.println("result " + a + b); //OUTPUT: result 1020
        System.out.println(a + b);             //OUTPUT: 30
        System.out.println(a + b + "result "); //OUTPUT: 30result
        System.out.println(a + b + "result " + a + b);  //OUTPUT: 30result 1020
    }
```

DOUBT:
When we do "result " + a + b we are getting concatenation of all, i.e output = result 1020

But when we do a + b + "result ", we are getting addition and then concatenation,i.e output = 30result, as per the above logic shouldn't output be output = 1020result...........?

Can someone please explain to me all 4 print statements of what is happening as some cases concatenation is taking precedence over addition and vice versa in other cases...can someone please give clarity on what exactly is happening in all 4 print cases mentioned in the above code?`

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313253/precedence-in-strings-in-java#29313288
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340207/java-string-concatenation-with-operator

Comment: See the official specification [JLS 15.18. Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) and [15.7. Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)